# カスタムディレクティブにおける window is not defined エラー

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

## 概要

Nuxt.jsでフロントエンドの開発をしております。
スクロールした際に要素をふわっと表示させるため、下記Vue.jsドキュメントの通りに実装をしています。

[カスタムスクロールディレクティブの作成](https://jp.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/creating-custom-scroll-directives.html)

その際、`window is not defined` のエラーが出ます。原因がわからず先に進むことができず困っています。ご教示のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

## エラー

`$yarn dev`コマンドにてローカルサーバー起動時

[image: Image from Gyazo]

## コード

plugins/scroll.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.directive('scroll', {
  inserted: function(el, binding) {
    let f = function(evt) {
      if (binding.value(evt, el)) {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', () => f, false)
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => f)
  }
})
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
~略~
 plugins: [
    {
      src: '~plugins/scroll.js',
      ssr: false
    }
]
```

pages/index.vue

```
<template>
    <a
      class="return-btn fade-in"
      @click="$vuetify.goTo('#top')"
      v-scroll="handleScroll()"
      :class="{ show: isShown }"
    >
      <img
        class="return-btn-img"
        src="~assets/images/return_btn.svg"
        alt="return_button"
      />
    </a>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
~略~
  methods: {
    handleScroll: function(evt, el) {
      if (window.scrollY > 50) {
        el.setAttribute(
          'style',
          'opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0)'
        )
      }
      return window.scrollY > 100
    },
</script>
```

## 追記

2020/01/15 `nuxt.config.js`に `mode: client`を指定してみましたが、エラー文は変わりませんでした。

```
 plugins: [
    {
      src: '~plugins/scroll.js',
      mode: 'client'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`v-scroll`属性を持った`a`タグがサーバサイドでレンダリングされているためです。
`a`タグを`<client-only>`で囲んでブラウザでレンダリングするように変更します。

```
<client-only>
<a
  class="return-btn fade-in"
  @click="$vuetify.goTo('#top')"
  v-scroll="handleScroll()"
  :class="{ show: isShown }"
>
  <img
    class="return-btn-img"
    src="~assets/images/return_btn.svg"
    alt="return_button"
  />
</a>
</client-only>
```